# Import a Multi-format Delimited File

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

I need to import a file into several database tables.  The file contains several simultaneous formats, like this:

```
901
902|1|Id|Name|Age
902|2|Id|Region|Address
902|3|Id|ProductName|ProductType|Price
903
1||Adam Sandler|40
1||Phil Collins|50
1||Fred Mason|22
2||Southwest|4000 Cactus Ln.
2||Northwest|5000 Seahawk Ln.
3||Surf board|recreation|$30.00
```

In effect, the "header" of this file (lines prefixed with '902') indicates what types of documents are contained (document type 1, 2, and 3) and what column names/quantities each document has.  Then the file provides the actual data (starting after the '903' designator).

I am required to use SSIS (SQL Server 2016) to import the data, but this doesn't seem like something for which SSIS has any built-in functionality.  So I'd like to hear suggestions of how to approach this.

Right now I believe I should [create a custom SSIS source component](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/developing-a-custom-ssis-source-component/).  Perhaps that custom approach will allow me to define a doc-type property that indicates which document-type I want to import (#1, #2, or #3) and then my custom C# code would do the heavy lifting.

Is that a good approach?  Is there a better approach? I am very strong with C#.

Comment: ... import into an "empty" table in the DB, then run statements that do `WHERE SUBSTRING(column, 1, 1) = '1'`?

Answer (score 0):

Too long to comment.

I'd use C# or Python or Batch or anything to split these into their own files prior to uploading them.

For example, one file for #1, one for #2, etc... My reason for this advice is you are only going to insert a single document type (as described by the header) in any given table. Thus, on import, it's best to have only the data needed for the table which you are inserting into in your file. I actually can't think of a clean way of doing it otherwise. So, you'd import file 1 into Table1, file 2 into Table2, and so on and so forth.

Of note, you wouldn't have to use SSIS for this if you didn't *want* to though it could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I load as lines with BULK

```
    CREATE TABLE #FileContent (Line varchar(2000));
    SET @sql='BULK INSERT #FileContent FROM '''+@FileFullName+'''  WITH (ROWTERMINATOR ='''+CHAR(10)+''')'
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC(@sql)
```

Then use split function to split the line data to columns
Take each format lines into different table.